# jQuery tablesorter loading indicator after filtering

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I've managed to get the 'loading' indicator working for when the page loads:

```
$("#product_list").tablesorter({
    initialized: function(){
        $('.wrapper').removeClass('loading');
    }
});
```

Is there a way to get this to work when a column filer is used?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), there is a [`showProcessing` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#showprocessing). When set to `true` a spinner will show up during filtering, sorting and ajax interactions.

Comment: Thanks, i was using 2.25.8 and just updated to 2.26. I then added 'showProcessing: true' but this then stopped my 'class="tablesorter-filter"' from working, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "stopped my `class="tablesorter-filter"` from working". Please elaborate. Also, it might help to set the `debug` option to `true` and look in the console for any issues.

Comment: Sorry I meant class="filter-onlyAvail", they no longer show the values that are available once I then add option 'showProcessing: true'.